# Замена кавычек на елочки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ребят есть ли регулярка заменяющая при выводе кавычки на елочки? Допустим в бд у меня есть запись "Тест" при выводе ее на сайте сменить кавычки на елочки «Тест»

Пример: есть такого вида данные, \"Тест\" на выходе должны получить «Тест»

Comment: А кавычки вложенными бывают...

Comment: Нет, всегда именно в таком виде, "текст"

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте примеры строк с желаемым результатом в вопрос, в противном случае точного ответа дать не сможет никто.

Comment: в комментариях ниже я все подробно изложил

Comment: @keaks88 Там ничего непонятно и не видно. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос + пару-тройку примеров, если вам нужен ответ быстрее.

Comment: добавил, хотя это не раз уже писал

Comment: Как спросили, такой ответ и получите. Я, при всем желании помочь, не понимаю, чем вам не нравится ответ Терана. Добавьте слеши, если они у вас есть перед кавычками, `preg_replace('/\\\\?"([^"]*)"/', '«$1»', $str)`.

Comment: Было бы все так легко))) Добавил, он все равно не заменяет

Answer (score 2):

Так что ли?

```
$str = '12 "34" 56  "78" 910 "1112';

$result = preg_replace('/"([^"]*)"/', '«$1»', $str);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: кстати заметил если допустим я текст тяну с бд, а в бд кавычки "" когда пишутся экранируются и когда выводятся тоже экранирование идет, вот тут уже не работает данная регулярка

Comment: дак и не надо ее применять на экранированных данных.

Comment: А для экранированных варианта нет? у меня все "" экранизируются при записи в бд

Comment: даже если я обработаю сначала экранированные stripslashes и потом уже выведу на сайт то результат все равно нулевой

Comment: в html-тегах эта регулярка тоже заменяет кавычки, так что никуда не годится.

Comment: @vadizar и при чем тут html тэги? Есть задача, есть решение. В задаче про тэги не было ничего

Comment: @teran данный ответ нужен не только автору вопроса. Так что выглядит как костыль, а не решение.

Comment: @teran тут очевидно, что редактируемый текст будет содержать форматирование, даже если автор вопроса не предвидел этот кейс.